# apt upgrade stuck on installing/upgrading open-vm-tools

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, upgrade, apt

I have a virtual machine based on Ubuntu 16.04. When using `apt update` and `apt upgrade` the upgrade process got stuck on upgrading `open-vm-tools`. Even after cancelling the process (logging in with another console) and killing the upgrade process (or rebooting), things did not change. This also happens when trying to `remove` or `purge` the package. After examining the problem I found that the upgrade process is stuck on `vmware-checkvm`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only offer a workaround. When killing the `vmware-checkvm` process (e.g., check via `ps fax`), the upgrading process continues normally.